# Cookie expiration time for countdown timer plugin

Tags: java, php, wordpress, cookies

I’m using a free plugin for Wordpress, that seems the author is not very proactive unfortunately, although it is a super useful and great plugin.

So I got an issue, as in the config for the plugin, it allows you to set an expiration time for a cookie in days, but I would like to know if it’s possible so i can amend the code and set it for minutes or seconds.

So I went into the plugin files, and found what I think is the actual piece of code that sets the cookie (sorry, but I'm not a programmer so I can’t really tell what this code does) so i was wondering if someone can help me on changing the actual code that controls the cookie expiration, and if it can be changed to accomplish what I need.

The plugin in question is the following:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-deadlines/

Thanks
Kind regards

Comment: Posting in the question the code snippet or a link to the code handling the cookie would help

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure if what i think is the code that defines the cookie expiration is actually the right one, as i said, im afraid im not programmer so I'm not so good on reading code...